Construct a copy of an object with nullable fields nulled if they haven't been changed since construction
I have Java classes with some nullable members, which get constructed from JSON objects with some optional keys. After construction, I will modify the objects, populating some previously-null members, and modifying or nulling some that existed in the JSON.
I need a method that will return a new object where all the nullable fields that I've filled in or modified remain populated, but the ones I didn't touch get nulled even if they weren't null when the object was constructed.
How can I accomplish this?

So you want to replace all unchanged initial values with null in the copy of the object? What a strange  requirement. Can you explain the purpose or use-case? This might be an XY problem.

Maybe use a builder pattern? Maybe have static methods that set the object's fields? Either way, some example code would be helpful. As is, this question doesn't show any research effort from your end.

Think about being the computer itself for this job. How can you tell the difference between these two fields:
String x;

and
String x;

Where one x is pointing at a string with value "Hello", and the other is pointing at the exact same string value. However, one of them was set after initialization, and the other was set before it.
The answer should be fairly obvious: Not possible.
Java doesn't add additional bookkeeping that would slow things down unless there's a very good reason for it, and here, there is not.
In other words, you have to do this bookkeeping yourself.
It is not possible in java to trigger some code to run when a field is updated. This is why the vast, vast majority of java code out there writes explicit (or, via lombok or records, implicit) getters and setters: By restricting all direct access to the field to code that is in your direct control, you are guaranteed that no user of your code will change that field without you being able to inject some code to run as part of the modification.
Thus, if you are not currently using setters, you have to in order to do this task. If / once you are, you'll have to invest in the considerable boilerplatey code to make this work. Given:
class Person {
  public String name;
  public LocalDate birthDate;
}

you'd first have to modify it to use getters and setters. Simply stick a @lombok.Data annotation from project lombok on there, or if you don't like lombok, write it out by hand:
// With lombok

@lombok.Data
class Person {
  private  String name;
  private LocalDate birthDate;
}

// by hand if you don't want to use lombok

class Person {
  private String name;
  private LocalDate birthDate;

  public String getName() { return this.name; }
  public String getBirthDate() { return this.birthDate; }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void setBirthDate(LocalDate birthDate) {
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
  }
}

Note that most IDEs have an option to do this for you, but that is a one-off deal (if you change a field name, you have to manually update that code or delete them and ask the IDE to re-generate them).
Once your class file looks like that, you add the boilerplate. Would look something like:
class Person {
  private String name;
  private boolean updatedName;

  private LocalDate birthDate;
  private boolean updatedBirthDate;

  public String getName() { return this.name; }
  public String getBirthDate() { return this.birthDate; }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.updatedName = true;
  }

  public void setBirthDate(LocalDate birthDate) {
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
    this.updatedBirthDate = true;
  }

  public Person getDelta() {
    Person p = new Person();
    p.name = updatedName ? this.name : null;
    p.birthDate = updatedBirthDate ? this.birthDate : null;
    return p
}

You could write a tool or framework to automate this process but that would be quite difficult. As in, I would not dare assign such a complicated task to anybody with less than 4 years coding experience and i'd give them at least a month. If you are looking for more details on how to get started on such a thing, feel free to post that in a comment and I'll try to update the answer. You won't like what I'll tell you, though.
